# How to add App List Image and Banner image when uploading odoo Theme application on odoo/themes

Tags: upload, themes, manifest, odoo, odoo-11

I am trying to upload odoo theme application to odoo/themes. I specified the two image files into my manifest file :

```
'images': [
        'static/description/horizontal_theme_poster.png',
        'static/description/landscape_screenshot.jpg',
    ],
```

`horizontal_theme_poster.png` is of size 360x460 and `landscape_screenshot.jpg` is of size 556x278.

After uploading the app, "landscape_screenshot.jpg" is shown on both - App List Image and Banner Image.
On App list Image is cropped to match app list image default size but its not loading the image that we I specifically wanted to load for.
I have seen other theme module upload two different images for both section.

Comment: App List Image, you mean Icon?

Comment: No. Its an image that is shown when you visit your app on odoo app-store.